# How is SPAN and Exposure Margin Determined on the NSE?

Tags: india, options, nse-india

Recently, I have been reading up a lot on writing options as this is something I am interested in. I came across a span margin calculator which asks me to enter the contract and it automatically calculates the SPAN and Exposure margins. Please correct me if I am wrong, but SPAN margin is the margin that needs to be put up and fulfilled on a daily basis. My question is, what is the exact formula that is used to calculate these margins and how do they come up with a particular number? A link to the margin calculator can be found [here](https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact logic for SPAN is developed by CME and may be proprietary and complex. A good article to understand the margins is available on the [NSE Site](http://www.nseindia.com/content/assist/asst_Margins_faq.pdf).

You can purchase [SPAN software](http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/pubspan/SPAN+Overview).